# Add scrollbars when SVG outsizes browser window

Tags: javascript, svg, embed

I have an issue here with an svg element embedded in html via an embed tag.  I just got my drag to resize functionality working for the graph that is being displayed, but when it is resized beyond the bounds of the browser window there is a problem because there are no scrollbars displayed.  Since there aren't scrollbars, the graph gets stuck off the screen, because the drag handle is at the bottom right, and off the screen.  I tried setting the overflow to scroll on the embed element, the body, the html, and various combinations of those.  I also tried adjusting the width of the svg and embed element, but that didn't do it either.  Also I tried switching the embed to an object tag, but that also did not seem to do the trick. Here is my styling for the .xhtml page

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0}
embed {  overflow:scroll; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #AAAAAA}
```

And here is the svg element definition in its file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
viewBox="0 0 1024 768" width="1024px" height="768px" 
onload="Initialize(evt)">
```

The resizing is accomplished by changing the scale attribute also, not changing the width and height.  Here's a link to the page so you can get a better idea of the problem(the red triangle is the scaling handle): http://reu.dimacs.rutgers.edu/~scottm/SVG/Bellman.xhtml. And a fiddle courtesy of Derek: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Cw9Dx/. Any help to add scrollbars when the svg outsizes the window would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hmm if I can I will-- but the svg file is something like 7000 lines with all the scripting commands so putting it directly in the html becomes an issue, and I'm not sure if I can externally link things with fiddle.  Are there any bits in particular that you would want to see?

Comment: Well I don't know much about XML (sorry about that), and IMO creating an example of the problem might help out others to understand the issue better.

Comment: I'll see if I can post a full working example, I just need to check with my professor who I'm doing the work for before I do.

Comment: Ok, here's an example.  The little red triangle at the bottom right is the handle to scale the graph.  http://reu.dimacs.rutgers.edu/~scottm/SVG/Bellman.xhtml

Comment: (I can't see the red triangle...)

Comment: What browser are you using?  It works for me in Firefox 13.01 and Chrome 19.0.1084.56

Comment: I guess it is because of my screen, too small. (4:3)

Comment: [I can see it now.](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Cw9Dx/) It looks like the scroll bars wil not come out is because you can't set `overflow` on `<embed>`..

Comment: Hmm, but if I switch to an <object> with overflow:scroll it still doesn't seem to allow scrolling if the graph outsizes the page.